# Windows/Linux portability

Tags: .net, mono, cross-platform, wine

I am wondering which of the following two options is more likely to work on Linux:

1. Native Win32 apps running with WINE
2. .Net apps running with Mono (assuming only using .Net 2 - including WinForms)

**Note 1:** By work, I mean will likely have all features implemented and working correctly, so that it can be run using the same *binary* under Linux.

**Note 2:** I am only interested in the above 2 options. Answers like "Use QT / Java / WxWidgets / [your favorite framework]" are not what I am looking for.

Comment: Both (for an app complidated enough) will require fixes, in the application or in the runtime.
_It all depends on the application in question._

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether you are asking about the planned or existing application. In the first case you should definitely go with Mono, because it is used to build *native* apps for Linux. Just to mention Banshee, Gnome Do, Tomboy, Plastic SCM etc. Developing (this way) on Windows with Linux as a deploy target (among others) is not so unusual as you may think. Inverse too ;)

On the other hand, if you have some existing application in mind, then involving probability seems to be strange here for me. Given existing application it will work or not - just try it. Or provide more details ;)